# The method bucket(String) is undefined for the type SubmissionRepositoryImpl

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am getting above error. I imported all required files too. Can any one help me with this.

```
public List<ScoreCount> scoreCount(String courseId, String assignmentId){
        Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("_id.courseId").is(courseId).and("_id.assignmentId").is(assignmentId)),
                bucket("overRollScore").withBoundaries(0, 20, 50, 70, 100).andOutput("score").push().as("gradeCount"));

        AggregationResults<ScoreCount> averageScore = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Submission.class, ScoreCount.class);

        return averageScore.getMappedResults();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating org.springframework.boot version from **1.4.1.RELEASE** to **1.5.3.RELEASE** in the POM file.